# Exclude with pattern in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Is there any way to add a pattern in the exclude property of a tsconfig file or is it only able to support directories?

I'm trying to exclude all my test files from compilation so I was wondering if I can use something like this :

```
src/**/*.spec.ts
```

Seems like it doesn't work though.

Comment: [Looks like they're working on it.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5980)

Comment: in the meanwhile, instead of excluding you can use `filesGlob` to indicate which files you want to include

Comment: Adding them in filesGlob will cause the files list to appear and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Somebody who can explain to me why one would exclude the spec/test files from typescript?

Comment: @Tanckom it's been so long since that post (and so much changed) that even I can't remember why I needed that.

Comment: Damnit - hope **somebody else picks up the previous comment** to explain the reason.

Comment: is there any way to make this work only on production build bundle?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Globs work in Typescript 2.0+. You would do `"exclude" : ["src/**/*.spec.ts"]` in your `tsconfig.json`.

**More**

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/project/files.html

Comment: Remember to remove the previous test files from the output folder after changing the configuration

Comment: @basarat hi i do this on my tsconfig.json, `"exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts"]`, but how to verify its already exclude when i run npm build?

Comment: you can use `tsc --listFiles` to see which files are included 

Answer (score 97):

Full example if anyone needs it:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The test files in the output directory has to be cleared! Else the test will still keep checking them

Comment: The downside of this is your tests won't be validated by typescript, and eventually your tests in your team might become quite bad typescript.

Comment: If I build to folder by name app_folder-v.1.2.3, how I exclude all folders with versions?